# Display HTML iframe in Bukkit client

Tags: java, html, minecraft, bukkit

I currently working on a project that requires display of a HTML `iframe` in the Bukkit client. Is it possible? And and how I can do it?

Comment: Render *what* in iFrame form? The server worlds? The console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to display HTML to the client unless it's a modded client. You can only use what is provided by the Bukkit API or Minecraft server.